# how to make padding for Drawer in react js material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have Drawer class component and I want to make marginTop for that Drawer, but I can't this is my code

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    root: {
        marginTop: '40px'
    },
})

class PageMenu extends React.Component {
    render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <Drawer
                classes={{paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
            >
            <List>
                {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                    <ListItem button key={text}>
                    <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
                </List>
                <Divider />
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    )}
```

i want to make it working in class component

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another class name to it and then style it in your CSS file by the following lines of code:

```
.classname{
     margin-top:yourNumber;
}
```